# Communicating with a combinational logic circuit

Tags: serial-port, serial-communication

I imagine this is a quite broad question, but i am wondering how i can communicate with a combinational logic circuit using my PC.

Can i use the RS232 serial port? I have looked into this and it seems like it only has one output and one input.

- What if my circuit has inputs A,B,C,... and so on?
- What about my clock signal?
- USB -- wouldn't i need software drivers and a microchip?
- Converting the RS232 12V & -12V to 0V & 5V respectively
- DC power source for the gates and what not?

Comment: Why do you want/need to do this with the serial port?  As you've stated, that's a poor solution to this problem.

Comment: I don't know what i should use. Hence my question "Can i use the RS232 serial port?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be using Arduino ( http://www.arduino.cc/ ). I seems really cool!